# Where does the t.GUID value come from in my RegisterFunction(Type t)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017

Where does `t.GUID` value come from on `Type t`. If I set the GUID in Visual Studio 2017, under the Project menu, Solution Properties, Application tab, Assembly Information, does that get associated with the t.GUID?

Comment: P.S.  I borrowed this code from another persons code, and am not familiar with the Register and Unregister code.

Comment: P.P.S Or is it one of the GUIDs from the sln file?

Comment: P.P.P.S. Maybe someone can help me Understand where and how all the GUIDs are used in the Visual Studio Environment.

Answer (score 0):

From [the .NET "Type" reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.guid?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> A GUID is associated with a type using the GuidAttribute attribute.

Where the [GuidAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) is applied to your class as follows:

```
[GuidAttribute("EE2BFDAD-CB79-494F-978E-1171B1FA131F")]
public class MyClass
{
}
```

The docs also say:

> Supplies an explicit Guid when an automatic GUID is undesirable.

So if no GUID is assigned then one is automatically assigned.

The GUID in your assembly information is for identifying your assembly as opposed to an individual Type.